# Order parent by it string children

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Data, I'm trying to get a list of products ordered by their tags as follow:

from this :

```
product_id | tags            |
-----------+-----------------+
     1     | tagB,tagD,tagI  |
     2     | tagA,tagB,tagC  |
     3     | tagA,tagB       |
     4     | tagB,tagC,tagI  |
```

achieve this result :

```
product_id | tags            |
-----------+-----------------+
     3     | tagA,tagB       |
     2     | tagA,tagB,tagC  |
     4     | tagB,tagC,tagI  |
     1     | tagB,tagD,tagI  |
```

the example's schema is simplified but actually is 2 tables : `products(id)` join `tags(pID, tag)`

this is my mapping and the `findAll` request :

```
@Entity
class Product {

 @Id
 Long parentID; 

 @ElementCollection
 @SortNatural
 List<String> tags;
 
}
```

```
Sort sortbytags = Sort.by( Arrays.aslist( Sort.Order.asc("tags") ) );
productRepository.findAll(specification, PageRequest.of(nb, size, sortby);
```

But whenever I execute the `findAll` request I get duplicated products depending on their tags size. if a product has 3 tags it appears 3 times in the list.

this is how I can achieve this in a native SQL query :

```
select 
ID, NAME, TAGS 
from PRODUCT 
left outer join (
    select PRODUCT_ID, string_agg(TAG, ',') as TAGS from (
        select      PRODUCT_ID, TAG 
        from        PRODUCT_TAGS  
        group by    PRODUCT_ID, TAG 
        order by    PRODUCT_ID, TAG
    ) group by PRODUCT_ID
)
on ID=PRODUCT_ID 
order by TAGs
```

does anyone knows how to have a similar request using spring data specification + criteria  ?

Comment: should I transform the tags from list to string and then sort ? how to do it with spring's Sort ?

Comment: Can you add an example of `findAll` method?

Comment: its spring JpaSpecificationExecutor's findAll method

Comment: Print the SQL generated.

Comment: `select product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.name as name2_0_ from product product0_ left outer join product_tags tags1_ on product0_.id=tags1_.product_id order by tags1_.tag asc`